# Solr Configuration for Hortontworks HA

Tags: solr, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm implementing the Hortonworks Standby NameNode (High Availibility) and i'm wondering how to configure the Solr to point to the cluster name instead of the Name node Hostname? As the name node might change in case of the failover.

str name=solr.hdfs.home: ??????

I tried to configure Dolr in several ways without succes:

1) Using the cluser name

2) using a "," separate host name of the both active and standby NameNode

3) using a ";" separate host name of the both active and standby NameNode

Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks
Regards
Farhad

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the cluster name instead of single namenode's FQDN. Cluster name must be defined during the creation of HA cluster, the same clustername should be given for **solr.hdfs.home** to achieve HA. Also hadoop client configurations(hdfs-site.xml,core-site.xml) should be available with solr running machine. This directory (where *site.xml file resides) should point to **hadoop.home** system property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the hdfs configuration dir `-Dsolr.hdfs.confdir={hadoop_conf}` at startup. In Hortonworks is usually `/etc/hadoop/conf`